# Button's background on ios7 is squeezed, ios6 ok

Tags: iphone, uibutton, ios7

I just updated to XCode 5. Buttons in my app look OK in IB and on iOS 6 device, but on iOS 7 device they look like this (they should cover the whole black space):

[image]

I have images for both non-retina/retina.

I have no idea what to do, because I didn't change anything in code or IB.

**EDIT:**

Now I found out, if I change type of button from custom to system and set its background instead of its image, I get the correct size but I get some strange shadow over it.

**EDIT2:**

Now I set button's tint color to "clear color" and everything seems ok (shadow disappeared). Still not sure what has changed in iOS 7 related to this.

Comment: in iOS 7, the navigation bar is default to be translucent, that means the frame of self.view is different than in 6.

Comment: Are you setting up the buttons in code or in a xib/storyboard? If code, please post

Comment: In IB. If i set button as selected in IB, everything looks ok.

Comment: What screensize you are using in xib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Human Interface Guidelines specifically outline how system-style UIButtons work by default. [It explains that a system button:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW10)

- Has no border or background appearance by default ...
- Supports custom decoration, such as a border or background image (to
  add a custom appearance, use a button of type `UIButtonTypeCustom` and
  supply a custom background image).

However the [UIButton HIG page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIButton) provides a little more information, specifically:

> If you do not explicitly set a tint color, the button will inherit its superview’s tint color.

This explains why, after changing your button to `UIButtonTypeSystem`, you suddenly have to reset (remove) the tint colour. In iOS7, (almost) *everything* has a tint colour. A `UIButtonTypeSystem` is more appropriate for your needs now in iOS7 (a bit of a pain if there's a lot to manually change though...)

As to why the buttons shrink in iOS7... I agree with @Joseph's comment regarding `UIViewController` view frames in iOS7. Likely you have some set relation for the size of the buttons that does not play nicely when the ViewController's frame changes in iOS7 (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18276248/1618592) for discussion). As advised there, check out the [iOS7 transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html) to see if anything you're doing in IB is going against the new iOS7-grain.

Answer (score 0):

`[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255.0) green:(180.0/255.0)];`.

This is the right code for background, and if you are use image then use

`[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"];`