# Extend edges programmatically

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an old app that is having strange layout behavior because of iOS7. It is not a storyboard app.

I started a storyboard app and came across 'Extend Edges' in the inspector, which seems to solve the issue on that particular app, however I don't have those options in my old app.

Is there a way for me to programmatically set those options?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios 7 UiView frame issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276248/ios-7-uiview-frame-issue)

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Answer (score 4):

In the newer swift version, the usage of Extended Layout is little bit changed.

```
In SWIFT 2
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None

In SWIFT 3
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```